# Get Spring UserDetails object at run time

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring application that the user must login by 3 fields (username, department ID, and password). I want to retrieve the department ID of the current logged in user at run time

I tried:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

And then tried to cast it to UserDetails object, but an error occurs saying that the object can't be cast.

I also tried to extend the UserDetails interface and add the required data to be returned, then I implemented the new interface, but I also can't cast the object.

Comment: The Authentication method will return an `Authentication` object which you need to cast appropriately to get the user details.

Comment: You are missing getPrincipal(); Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(); if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
  String username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
} else {
  String username = principal.toString();
}

Comment: also you may want to add details of the AUthentication object you're trying to get the details of.

Answer (score -1):

If JWT is used, then add claim during token build
String jwt = Jwts.builder()
  .setSubject(username)
  .claim("deptId", departmentId)

Then fetch the value from claims.getBody()

Comment: How is this helpful?